Cloudflare protection on Stack Overflow related sites
Cloudflare always asks me for human validation while visit Stack Overflow related sites, I know the reason is because I'm using a VPN software to surfing the network, It will back to normal after I close it, but I have to use it.
It's just kind of annoying to click the checkbox provided by Cloudflare every time.
Is there any solution so I can avoid this?

If this happens on al SE network sites, maybe MSE is a better place for this question

Have you done any general web searching for how to avoid the issue causing CF to flag your connection as requiring additional validation? If you use a different VPN, do you get the same prompts? Using a VPN is a very good reason for a CDN like CF to require additional validation, especially if the endpoints of the VPN you're using are used by malicious actors.
